# How to force Zephyr LLM to respond in English only - randomly responds in French

Tags: large-language-model

I have worked with Llama2 and never got this number of random responses in another language.  In Zephry with the system prompt below, still every now and then responds in French...

Am I setting up my system prompt incorrectly?  Or is there some other way to do this where I don't have to tell it to respond in english every single interaction?

```
# create the prompt template
prompt_template: str = """/
<|system|>
You are a helpful, respectful and honest assistant. 

Use the following pieces of context to answer the question at the end. 

Always respond to questions using the English language, please translate all answers to English if in another language first.  

Your answers should not include any harmful, unethical, racist, sexist, toxic, dangerous, or illegal content. 

Please ensure that your responses are socially unbiased and positive in nature.  

If a question does not make any sense, or is not factually coherent, explain why instead of answering something incorrectly. 

If you don't know the answer to a question, please don't share false information.
</s>
{context}
{chat_history}
<|user|>
{question}
</s>
<|assistant|>"
"""

PROMPT = PromptTemplate.from_template(template=prompt_template)

## display prompt format as template:
PROMPT
```

Comment: Even I'm facing the same issue with Zephyr. Randomly some responses it gives in French